# Projectile motion question in regards to a circle that has a radius of 1.0 meters

Tags: trigonometry

An object moves in a circular path with a radius of 1.0 m from P to Q; clockwise (90 degrees) and counter-clockwise (270 degrees). Enter the displacement magnitude and direction in both cases.

Answer is 1,4 m in the SouthEast direction (in both cases); however, I can't understand how they solved this problem. I just added the radius and got 3.0 but that's obviously wrong.

Help if you can. The problem comes with a diagram but I can't find a similar one on the internet. There are two diagrams consisting of circles both divided into 4 quadrants with an arrow designating the area occupied.The clockwise arrow is within the 1st quadrant and the the counter clockwise arrow is in the 2nd, 3rd and 4th.

Answer (score 1):

Note that we are dealing with **vectors**. Thus, the actual path from $P$ to $Q$ doesn't matter; all that matters is where it started and where it stopped.

Consider the unit circle in the Cartesian plane (centred at $(0,0)$ with radius $1$). Let $P$ be the point $(0,1)$. Then by rotating $P$ clockwise $90^\circ$, we find that point $Q$ is at $(1,0)$. Note that if we had instead rotated $270^\circ$ counterclockwise, we would still end up at the same point; this explains why both answers are the same.

Using the distance formula between points (or by using the Pythagorean Theorem), we find that the magnitude of the displacement is $\sqrt{1.0^2+1.0^2}=\sqrt{2.0}\approx1.4~m$. The direction is $\arctan{(1.0/1.0)}=45^\circ$ south of east, or simply southeast.

Comment: Great explanation. Thank you!!